# How to find the First Control in Tab Order in a Control?

Tags: c#, tabindex, tab-ordering

I write an Extension method to get the *First Control in Tab Order* in a `Control` as below:

```
public static void FirstControlFocus(this Control ctl)
{
    ctl.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(c => c.TabIndex == 0).FirstOrDefault().Focus();
}
```

The problem is sometimes the maybe there is no existing control with `TabOrder==0`!(for example developer delete the control with `Taborder==0` in design mode) and this lead to error in runtime.

I handle this problem with this code:

```
public static void FirstControlFocus(this Control ctl)
{
    if (ctl.Controls.OfType<Control>().Any(c => c.TabIndex == 0))
        ctl.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(c => c.TabIndex == 0).FirstOrDefault().Focus();
    else if (ctl.Controls.OfType<Control>().Any(c => c.TabIndex == 1))
        ctl.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(c => c.TabIndex == 1).FirstOrDefault().Focus();
    else if (ctl.Controls.OfType<Control>().Any(c => c.TabIndex == 2))
        ctl.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(c => c.TabIndex == 2).FirstOrDefault().Focus();
    else if (ctl.Controls.OfType<Control>().Any(c => c.TabIndex == 3))
        ctl.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(c => c.TabIndex == 3).FirstOrDefault().Focus();
}
```

But I think it's not the *best* way, Could anyone suggest a better way to handle this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Min()`:

```
public static void FirstControlFocus(this Control ctl)
{
    ctl.Controls.OfType<Control>()
       .FirstOrDefault(c => c.TabIndex == ctl.Controls.OfType<Control>().Min(t => t.TabIndex))
      ?.Focus();
}
```

There is no need in `Where()` - you can use `FirstOrDefault()` only. Also, consider using `?.Focus()` in case if `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null`.

Comment: whats the `?` after `FirstOrDefault()`?